# Rest request signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

i am writing a Coinegg Client with Nodejs. I already did it for another exchange and everything went well, after alot of reading. This time i'am stuck because of the lack of information from coinegg.

The description of the api requests is hard to interpret, maybe anybody got a clue.
"signature -- Parameters like "amount", "price", "type", "nonce", "key" will be combined by '&' to create a new string, encrypt the new string by Sha256 algorithm, key is md5(private key)" 
Link:

> https://www.coinegg.com/explain.api.html

My code looks as follows:

```
const getMessageSignature = (data, secret) => {
    const dataString = qs.stringify(data);
    const hash = new crypto.createHash('md5').update(secret, 'base64').digest('hex');
    const hmac = new crypto.createHmac('sha256', hash).update(dataString, 'base64').digest('hex');
    return hmac;
};
```

Data will be stringified to key=value&.... 
also tried it with value&value... same result.

Found another javascript api but he used another library(crypto-js) instead of the shipped library(crypto).

I'am stuck and curious.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a buffer for the dataString and the secret in utf-8 encoding.
Then update both functions also in utf-8 and return them as hex. 
Like so:

```
const dataString = qs.stringify(data);
const data_buffer = Buffer.from(dataString, 'utf-8');
const key_buffer = Buffer.from(secret, 'utf-8');
const hash = new crypto.createHash('md5').update(key_buffer, 'utf-8').digest('hex');
const hmac = new crypto.createHmac('sha256', hash).update(data_buffer, 'utf-8').digest('hex');
```